# How do you write this in notations?

Tags: number-theory

Refer to the link below by Numberphile https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Vj_7Y2-xY

I have found that integer solution set for $(a^2+b^2)/(ab+1)$ can be represented by $[x,f(x)]$, $[f(x),g(x)]$ and series of iterative $[g(x),h(x)]$ for $x>1$
where :
$$f(x) = x^3$$
$$g(x)= [f(x) * \frac{\sqrt{x^4 - 4} + x^2}{2}]$$
$$h(x) =[g(x)* \frac{\sqrt{x^4 - 4} + x^2}{2}]$$
$$Note: [\ ]\ represents \ round \ function.$$

My issue is that the last h(x) needs to be iterative, I mean for instance , for $x=2$, $f(x) = 2^3 = 8$ hence one set is $(2,8)$

Similarly $g(x) = [f(x) * (sqrt(n^4 - 4) + n^2) / 2]$ = $[8 * (sqrt(12)+4)/2]$ = $30$ hence second set is $(8,30)$

Now $h(x) = [30*(sqrt(12)+4)/2] = 112$ hence the next one is $(30,112)$ and from here it needs to be seed based where the next element needs to be $[112, [112*(sqrt(12)+4)/2]]$ & so on...

I hope you got my point. Any idea how to write such solution set with right notations? (Sorry if some of my notations are off)

Comment: BTW I am just looking for an alternative method, I know the answer as discussed over there by vieta jumping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[x_0,y_0]$ with $y_0=x_0^3$

$[x_n,y_n]$ for $n \ge 1$ such that $x_n=y_{n-1}$ and $y_n=\left [y_{n-1} \times  \frac{\sqrt{x_0^4 - 4} + x_0^2}{2} \right]$